# flashplayer security doubts

Tags: 12.04, flash, security

I am an Ubuntu newbie and I installed Ubuntu Desktop 12.04, 64 bit. As I noticed the Firefox is the actual version, but the Adobe Flashplayer was the 11.2 version which has, I guess, some security problems?

I was connected to the Internet for several days before I noticed that the Flashplayer is 11.2.

My question is - is there any chance of my PC being infected now? Can BIOS be infected, or if I format the HD and install Ubuntu again everything will be fine?

Answer (score 3):

`11.2` is just the major version. The actual current version is `11.2.202.297` and that is a maintenance release for `11.2`, released in July 2013, including the same fixes that the `11.8` major version received.

From Adobe:

> Flash Player 11.2 is the last supported Flash Player version for Linux OS. Adobe will continue to provide security updates.

I'm not sure how long that will continue but they *still* maintain a 10.something extended support release, so we're hopefully good for a few years yet.

Ignore [Mozilla Plugincheck](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/). [It doesn't know what it's talking about](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/960477).

Comment: Yes, I am running the 11.2.202.297 version. But was it possiple for me to get infected when I surfed the internet using firefox for several days? I read that it is possible for a website to run some code on my pc using  this version of flash player.

Comment: That's my point - you're using a version of Flash that is updated with the latest security patches. I won't say your computer is invulnerable but you are no more vulnerable through Flash than somebody using the latest 11.8 version.

Comment: Hello Oli, thank you for the reply. There is an option in firefox to check if the versions of the add-ons are actual, I did it and it says that flash player must be updated. I really don't know what to do... or how to check if I am potentially disposed to a virus attack?

Comment: @Barbara Edited.