# I can't install flash on ubuntu 14.04 to play facebook games, videos or youtube videos

Tags: firefox, flash

I can't install flash on Ubuntu 14.04 to play facebook games, videos or youtube videos.

I'm using firefox.
I've installed Ubuntu restricted extras.

Comment: What problem are you getting ? Please show us the steps you are doing and any error messages. Thanks.

Comment: I installed it using ubuntu software center but it's not working.
and also tried the sudo command for installing it but still not working

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be trying Google Chrome, which has flash built in.  If you also need to install java support to your browsers, I recommend using the iced tea plugin here

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: Installing Google Chrome is simple, just download either the 32-bit or 64-bit .deb file from the Chrome website (it will run in the Ubuntu Software Center).

Comment: To install the Java plugin, first install the runtime then install the plugin     sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre      sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin

Answer (score 2):

### How to manually install Adobe's Flash NPAPI plugin for browsers such as Firefox, Iceweasel and SeaMonkey

1. Access https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/
2. Select your architecture: **Linux (32-bit)** or **Linux (64-bit)**.

   - If you're unsure about your system's architecture, run the shell command `uname -i`: if it returns something having the number **64** in it, your system is 64-bit. Otherwise, it's 32-bit.
3. Download the **NPAPI tarball**: select the option having `(.tar.gz) - NPAPI` in it and then click onto the "Download now" button.

   - A tarball is a file with a ".tar.xxx" extension, where "xxx" is an extension for compressed files, like e.g. **zip**, **gz**, **bz2**, **7z** etc. Hence, `tarball.tar.gz`, `tarball.tar.zip`, `tarball.tar.7z` and `tarball.tar.bz2` are all examples of tarballs.
4. Save the tarball into the `/tmp` folder with the name **flash.tar.gz**. If your browser automatically downloads the tarball, thus making it impossible for you to rename the tarball before the download starts, wait for the download to end, then go to the folder where the tarball's been put, rename the tarball to **flash.tar.gz** and then move it to `/tmp`.
5. Start the shell terminal and then run this command:

   ```
   cd /tmp ; tar -xvf flash.tar.gz
   ```
6. Now run this supercommand in order to place the Adobe Flash plugin in the system folder:

   ```
   if ! [ -d /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/ ]; then sudo mkdir /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin ; else echo /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/ already exists ; fi ; sudo cp -f libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/ ; sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
   ```
7. Then run this command in order to place the Adobe Flash folders in their respective locations:

   ```
   sudo cp -rf /tmp/usr /
   ```
8. You can now run your Mozilla/Gecko browser (Firefox, Iceweasel or SeaMonkey) and then access the URL `about:plugins` in order to check if your browser has detected the flash plugin located at `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so` (it should be also visible by accessing `about:addons` and then the **Plugins** section). If you see something like **Shockwave Flash 24.0 r0**, then go to http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about in order to check if the flash applet detects your NPAPI flash install and tells you which version you're currently using.

   - It's possible that your browser will show the plugin location as being `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so` instead of `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so`. If it happens, ignore it: it's normal.
9. Restart your computer just to make sure that the applications menu shows your brand-new "**Adobe Flash Player**" control panel. If it doesn't, you should be able to start it by running this shell command:

   ```
   /usr/bin/flash-player-properties
   ```

Note: if you're using the 32-bit SeaMonkey on a 64-bit system, the browser won't "see" the plugin. Use another browser (e.g. Firefox).

### How to manually uninstall Adobe's Flash NPAPI plugin for browsers such as Firefox, Iceweasel and SeaMonkey

Open a shell terminal window and run this supercommand:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so /usr/bin/flash-player-properties /usr/lib/kde4/kcm_adobe_flash_player.so /usr/lib64/kde4/kcm_adobe_flash_player.so /usr/share/applications/flash-player-properties.desktop /usr/share/kde4/services/kcm_adobe_flash_player.desktop /usr/share/pixmaps/flash-player-properties.png ; cd /usr/share/icons/hicolor ; sudo find . -name "flash-player-properties.png" -delete
```

---

### How to manually install Adobe's Flash PPAPI plugin for a WebKit browser such as Opera

1. Access https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/
2. Select your architecture: **Linux (32-bit)** or **Linux (64-bit)**.

   - If you're unsure about your system's architecture, run the shell command `uname -i`: if it returns something having the number **64** in it, your system is 64-bit. Otherwise, it's 32-bit.
3. Download the **PPAPI tarball**: select the option having `(.tar.gz) - PPAPI` in it, and then hit the "Download now" button.

   - A tarball is a file with a ".tar.xxx" extension, where "xxx" is an extension for compressed files, like e.g. **zip**, **gz**, **bz2**, **7z** etc. Hence, `tarball.tar.gz`, `tarball.tar.zip`, `tarball.tar.7z` and `tarball.tar.bz2` are all examples of tarballs.
4. Save the tarball into the `/tmp` folder with the name **pepflash.tar.gz**. If your browser automatically downloads the tarball, thus making it impossible for you to rename the tarball before the download starts, wait for the download to end, then go to the folder where the tarball's been put, rename the tarball to **pepflash.tar.gz** and then move it to `/tmp`.
5. Start the shell terminal and then run this command:

   ```
   cd /tmp ; tar -xvf pepflash.tar.gz
   ```
6. Now run these commands in order to place the Adobe Flash plugin in the system folder:

   ```
   if ! [ -d /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/ ]; then sudo mkdir /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin ; else echo /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/ already exists ; fi ; sudo cp -f libpepflashplayer.so /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/ ; sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libpepflashplayer.so
   ```
7. You can now run your WebKit / Opera browser, then access the URL `about:plugins` in order to check if your browser has detected the flash plugin located at `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so`. Don't forget to click the **Show details** button (upper right) in order to expand the information fields and show extra info about each detected plugin. If you see something like **Adobe Flash Player** located at `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so`, then go to http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about just to make sure that the flash applet detects your PPAPI flash install and tells you which version you're currently using.

### How to manually uninstall Adobe's Flash PPAPI plugin for a WebKit browser such as Opera

Open a shell terminal window and run this command:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so
```

---

### How to manually install Adobe's Flash PPAPI plugin for Google Chrome and Google Chromium browsers

If you're using Google Chrome/Chromium, it already comes with its own bundled **PPAPI** Flash plugin located at `~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/some_version_number/libpepflashplayer.so`. However, if videos aren't working with Google Chrome/Chromium when you're on Facebook, YouTube et cetera (you hear the audio, but doesn't see any video), then you're probably trying to watch **HTML5** videos but your GPU (Graphics Processing Unit) has a built-in rendering blacklist that's avoiding video acceleration required by HTML5.

In order to fix this issue, start Google Chrome/Chromium, access this URL:

```
chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blacklist
```

...then **activate** the above option and restart Google Chrome/Chromium.

If the above solution doesn't solve the issue, follow the 6 steps provided at **How to manually install Adobe's Flash PPAPI plugin for a WebKit browser such as Opera**, then back up Google's PepperFlash plugin and create a symbolic link to Adobe's flash PPAPI plugin.

If e.g. your Chrome/Chromium browser is using PepperFlash plugin version 24.0.0.186 and you downloaded Adobe's flash PPAPI plugin version 24.0.0.186 (same version of Google's PepperFlash), then this is the shell command you'll have to issue **after you install Adobe's Flash PPAPI plugin**:

```
mv ~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/24.0.0.186/libpepflashplayer.so ~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/24.0.0.186/libpepflashplayer.so.bak ; sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so ~/.config/google-chrome/libpepflashplayer.so
```

### How to manually uninstall Adobe's Flash PPAPI plugin for Google Chrome and Google Chromium browsers

Open a shell terminal window and run this command:

```
sudo rm ~/.config/google-chrome/libpepflashplayer.so ; mv ~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/24.0.0.186/libpepflashplayer.so.bak ~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/24.0.0.186/libpepflashplayer.so
```

---

Answer (score 0):

First install jre on Ubuntu, then follow the wiki to create a symbolic link of libpng.so in mozilla plug-ins