# safe boot in linux, Ubuntu update

Tags: software-installation

I was about two thirds finished with updating Ubuntu when my computer, an older macbook pro, just shup itself off.  Now when I try to start it up it  tries to boot straight to Ubuntu instead of Linux and just freezes on the start up screen.  I had hoped to fix a problem I was having playing a game with flash player.

Comment: What do you mean, "it tries to boot straight to ubuntu instead of Linux" ? Ubuntu is Linux.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot in **Recovery Mode**, as explained here:

   [How do I boot into recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode)
2. Now in Recovery Mode, run `touch /forcefsck` in order to schedule a disk check for the next boot.
3. Run `apt-get update` in order to check if your Internet connection is up. If it **is**, just run:

   ```
   apt-get clean && apt-get check && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove -y
   ```
4. If the apt-get commands were executed as expected, restart your system:

   ```
   sudo telinit 6
   ```
5. If your Internet connection isn't working, run this command in order to enable the network device:

   - If your computer is connected by cable:

     ```
     ifconfig eth0 up
     ```
   - If your computer is connected by a wireless network device (wifi):

     ```
     ifconfig wlan0 up && rfkill unblock 0
     ```
   - - The above commands won't give you any feedback unless some problem occurs. If you're attempting to connect via wifi, run the following command in order to make your computer scan for nearby wireless networks available:

       ```
       iwlist wlan0 scan
       ```
   - - See which wireless network you want to connect to, then run this command:

       ```
       iwconfig wlan0 essid ID key s:PWD
       ```
   - - **Note**: replace `ID` with the name (SSID) of the wireless network. Also, replace `PWD` with the password required to connect to such network.
   - - After you establish an Internet connection, execute the item 3 and then the item 4, above.
6. If your computer boots correctly, your next step will be installing Adobe Flash. You can follow the link below in order to perform such installation:

   [I can't install flash on ubuntu 14.04 to play facebook games, videos or youtube videos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470281/i-cant-install-flash-on-ubuntu-14-04-to-play-facebook-games-videos-or-youtube/757874#757874)