# How do I manually install Adobe Flash player for Chromium?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, flash, chromium, pepperflash

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04.1

For external reasons I cannot use apt-get.

I downloaded flash_player_ppapi_linux.x86_64.tar.gz and have extracted it but I don't know where to put each of the files, the readme does not have instructions.

In the archive are a few legal text files, the readme, libpepflashplayer.so and manifest.json.

Comment: Which are the "external reasons" why you can't use `apt-get`? To me it sounds like a severely broken system.

Comment: Indeed but this is  more urgent/currently possible with what I have at hand. 

I'm a Linux hobo right now, living out of a USB stick because my hard drive died on me in the middle of finals week hahahaha.

Answer (score 0):

Search your /usr/lib directory for Chromium's addons or plugins directory. (It may look like chromium-plugins or chromium/addons or chromium/plugins etc.)

Once this has been identified, open the terminal and cd into it. Then use:

```
sudo cp libpepflashplayer.so <plugins directory location>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's still not showing up in chrome://plugins

Comment: What directory did you place it in?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the answer I provided [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470281/i-cant-install-flash-on-ubuntu-14-04-to-play-facebook-games-videos-or-youtube/757874#757874) and [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341428/how-to-install-flash-player-on-ubuntu/879433#879433). It explains how to manually:

- Install Adobe's NPAPI flash plugin for Firefox
- Uninstall Adobe's NPAPI flash plugin for Firefox
- Install Adobe's PPAPI flash plugin for Opera
- Uninstall Adobe's PPAPI flash plugin for Opera
- Install Adobe's PPAPI flash plugin for Chrome/Chromium
- Uninstall Adobe's PPAPI flash plugin for Chrome/Chromium