# Videos from youtube (ONLY) are not streaming in any browser in UBUNTU GNOME 14.04 LTS x64

Tags: firefox

I have tried using firefox, chromium, chrome, epiphany, but nothing seem to work. Few days back, youtube was working like a charm and suddenly it stopped working. I had ubuntu-restricted-extras installed in my system. I have tried uninstalling previous flash package and installing other flash packages like adobe-flashplugin, flashplugin-installer, libflashplayer.so (which came in some package from adobe.com), gnash (one at a time). gnash is even unable to stream the videos from youtube. Although, flash seem to be installed correctly (confirmed by about:plugins in firefox). Do not suggest me to purge remove flash again as i did it like 10 times.

In case my system's configuration is relevant, here it is:

```
RUNNING IN: Vmware Workstation 10
CPU: AMD A8-4500M (given 2 cores)
GPU: AMD 7640G+7670M
RAM: 4 GB (given 2 GB)
```

(PS: I experience a lot of problems in linux for having AMD machine)

Comment: Can you try using the HTML5 player?

Comment: @Tim yes HTML5 is working but it doesn't work as nice as flash does. It takes a lot of time to load and stream in my place (with my internet connection).

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem, occasionally I have to disable it. I am guessing that everything is updated and you've restarted completely?

Comment: @Tim I did a 'dist-upgrade' just now.....still the same.
BTW how do you disable HTML5?

Comment: You can use: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-youtube-html5-pla/enmofgaijnbjpblfljopnpdogpldapoc in chrome.

Comment: Have you tried questions like this: [How to install Flash player on Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/341428/how-to-install-flash-player-on-ubuntu) and this: [How do I install Adobe Flash Player](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

Comment: @Tim do you use gnome too??

Comment: @Wilf I have tried flashplayer plugin, google chrome and gnash plugin already. And now I am giving a try to install Pipelight and Pepper as mentioned in questions you pointed.

Comment: No, I'm using unity.

Comment: For Mozilla Firefox make sure that you install the native flash player plugin.  `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-insttaller`.  Then open the url "about:plugins" and search for flash `libflashplayer.so`, and make sure that its there.  Now keep in mind that flash player does not receive updates (except security updates) anymore. Version 11.2.202.350 was the last release.  See [Here](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/).

Comment: @Mitch I read in some post that flashplugin-installer package is not appropriate for x64 systems while adobe-flashplugin is. However, I have tried each of them to make it work, but still the same. 
BTW this are plugins installed in my chrome and firefox 
http://s8.postimg.org/u49ynvw11/Chrome.png

http://s8.postimg.org/zeexf6g9x/Firefox.png

Comment: @Mitch "/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/" seem to be empty

Comment: Just copy `libflashplayer.so` to the plugins directory in Firefox.

Comment: that's weird but the problem came back after a restart

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem in windows now, which i guess is due to bad youtube server.
It is going on and off automatically.
Thanks anyways!!