# Change the color depth

Tags: games, colors

This is a real problem on Ubuntu -- the color depth adjustment. I have an AMD A8 computer with 16GB ram and SSD drive SATA3 and the computer lags with Tetris (which is a very basic flash game) on Facebook.

Okay, you guys may be very proud to lose a game with magnificent 24-bit color depth screen.

I would like to set the color to 8-bit or even 256 colors as long as I win the game!

Can someone tell me why something so useful is impossible?

Missing the color depth adjustment on the screen windows is a real issue, how do you want people enjoy gaming with Ubuntu?

Comment: That is configured from your monitor.

Comment: @Lucio: No, to put it simply.

Answer (score 3):

The lag in Tetris is not going to be related to your colour depth, and changing colour depth is not going to make it any faster (and may just make it slower, particularly if you succeed in moving to a palette based colour mode).

Presuming that it's a Flash-based app in the browser, it'll have everything to do with Flash support.

There are several issues here:

- Adobe no longer support Flash on linux, so you can't get a recent version.  Depending on your Ubuntu version you may be able to still get Flash 11.2, from the `flashplugin-installer` package in multiverse - otherwise follow instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341428/how-to-install-flash-player-on-ubuntu) for using the "pepper" support in Chrome.
- If you don't use Adobe's own Flash plugin, you'll be using one of the open source alternatives, which are likely to have very poor, slow performance.

Comment: This is the right answer. If it's just about playing Tetris and no social interaction placed around it, I suggest you search for “Tetris“ in the software centre and try out one or more of the offered games.