# i can't download adobe flash player

Tags: flash, downloads, adobe

I have ubuntu 14.04 and i need to download adobe flash player,but when i go to the main page on the bottom right corner on top of the download button it says "Note: Your antivirus software must allow you to install software." does anyone know how i can download it?

Comment: Here is how it's done: [How to install Flash player on Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/341428/how-to-install-flash-player-on-ubuntu), and another nice one: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Flash-Player-on-Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are getting this error message in browser. Regarding this kindly check whether previous version of adobe is available and try uninstalling it and also remove the dependencies from the installation location and try reinstalling it using the below command.

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

If above not working then just downloaded it (again) from here: http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/ (choose your OS and the version "for other browsers") and check.

Comment: Nope, take a look at [this page](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/), bottom right. It really says "Note: Your antivirus software must allow you to install software."