# Is Flash player software installed on Ubuntu by default?

Tags: flash

Do we need to download flashplayer on Ubuntu or is it already there?

I installed it on my PC just by passing the command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get insall flashplugin-installer
```

And it doesn't seem to be downloading but it works after the installation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Flash player on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341428/how-to-install-flash-player-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @N0rbert: I don't think this question is covered by the stated duplicate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on which version you installed. If you installed 16.04, and chose to install certain 3rd party software, `flashplugin-installer` was probably installed to start with.

From Ubuntu 17.10 Flash will not be installed by default, but you need to install it explicitly. The reason is that Flash as such will be EOL before the end of the 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Thank you, but in my PC, I tried to install flash-player while my it was connected to INTERNET, and when I passed the command 'sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer', my pc installed flash player which was not already. So my question is that, was the software already in the PC or it first DOWNLOADED and then installed?

Comment: @Divyanshusalve: It was both downloaded from the Ubuntu archive - behind the scenes - and installed. That's what normally happens when you install with `apt-get install` (or `apt install`):