# Adobe flash player on 18.04 "the channel bionic partner is unknown"

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, flash

How can I install Adobe flash player on 18.04 LTS? I have tried downloading it from the Adobe Flash official site where I select the Ubuntu/Debian version, but it says chose an application to open the download link, and the only option that appears is Apt-URL. When I select it I get a popup saying

> the channel bionic partner is unknown

Enabling the partner repository doesn't help.

How can I install Adobe flash on 18.04?

Comment: In what circumstance you need that? In what browser?

Comment: I ran into this problem, and [karel's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/990925/527764) to the linked post fixed it. Just close the Adobe page, do the installation as explained in that answer, then restart the browser.

Answer (score 21):

Yesterday, I installed Flash Player on my PC and it works in latest Firefox.

I suggest you run this command in your terminal:

```
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: In order for this command to work, one has to check the "Canonical Partners" box in the Other Software tab in the Software & Updates.  See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/990925/384849