# Adobe Flash Player Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10

Anyone knows the commands to install Adobe Flash player and the packages needed for ubuntu 18.10?

Answer (score 2):

Enable Canonical Partners Repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Install Adobe Flash Plugin:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

Reset your browser and you should be all set.

Source:
https://websiteforstudents.com/install-adobe-flash-player-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-beta-desktop/

Comment: Great answer. Please consider posting it also on this question that has much more upvotes:  
https://askubuntu.com/questions/341428/how-to-install-flash-player-on-ubuntu