# 18.04 LTS: Download & install Adobe flash player

Tags: 18.04

I should like to be able to download and install Adobe flash player on Ubuntu. I am not familiar with either Ubuntu or it's use of terms. I should be best regarded as a simpleton when trying to achieve anything with Ubuntu. 
The version I have is 18. ?. This version is one of the type with long-term support. Many thanks, Geoffrey Lynn.

Comment: I searched for a duplicate question, but all candidates seem to be outdated or not applicable. So this question seems to be acceptable, or not?

Comment: There's a package `flashplugin-installer` you can install.

Comment: In a terminal, do `sudo apt update && sudo apt install flashplugin-installer`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Flash player on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341428/how-to-install-flash-player-on-ubuntu) While old, first two answers are still valid and correct. Personally, I prefers the second answer.